# Tool for teaching maths online

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm trying to find a good tool for teaching someone maths online. Some kind of a online whiteboard that the student can be invited to.

I need to be able to draw graphs and handwrite using my drawing tablet.
I also need to be able to type text and formulae.

Something with similar features to the Windows application [iDroo](http://www.idroo.com/features) would be great!

What online tool would be most suitable?

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/idroo/

Comment: Nowadays there is [softwarerecs.se] for questions asking for software recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be pretty much perfect: http://www.twiddla.com/

It even has support for LaTeX!

http://www.skrbl.com/ seems pretty good too as a slightly more basic alternative.

Also, here's quite a good list of interactive whiteboard related links, many of them whiteboard webapps: http://www.shambles.net/pages/staff/intwhiteb/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in case you can't find anything what you're looking for -- [Ustream](http://www.ustream.tv/) your whiteboard or tablet.

Answer (score 0):

- You could use [Yahoo! Doodle](http://ca.messenger.yahoo.com/imvironments/view/doodle/).
- Check out [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org) as well,
  Sal has made hundreds of great videos
  and just recently improved the
  feedback/statistical system for the
  online exercises.

Answer (score 0):

For Math and Science tutoring http://tutorsbox.com seems like a great tool.

- Function Grapher
- Equation Editor with LaTeX support
- Wolfram Alpha search engine integration